# How to update a dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

In my project, there are two textBoxes, `txtName` and `txtPopulation` and a Button, `btnClick`. whenever the user clicks `btnClick`, the value in the "Population" column of the dataset `dsDetails` should get updated by the value in `txtPopulation`, where the "Name" Column is equal to `txtName`. I know this can be done using `rowfilter` or `select` but I have no idea what to implement in it. **Please no linq**

[image]
Currently, I am doing something like this..(*working*)

```
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount++)
{
    if (lblCountryName.Text.Equals(dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][0].ToString()))
    {
         dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][3] = txtPopulation.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call `.AcceptChanges()` on your DataTable so your changes are committed to the collection, like this:

```
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount++)
{
    if (lblCountryName.Text.Equals(dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][0].ToString()))
    {
        dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][3] = txtPopulation.Text;
    }
}  

dsDetails.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

**Using select row filter**

You can target your column by using the `.Select` row filter, like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsDetails.Tables[0].Select("Name = '" + txtName.Text + "'"))
{
    row[3] = txtPopulation.Text;
}

dsDetails.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: @Mr_Green sorry, was a bit hasty there and didn't actually answer your question. Updated with the row filter.

Answer (score 2):

```
DataRow[] dr = dsDetails.Tables[0].Select("Something='"+lblCountryName.Text+"'");
if(dr.Length > 0)
{
 dr[0][0] = "ChangeValue";//Datarow is reference to datatable it will automatically update the datatable values
}
dsDetails.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

//this code will replace all data in all rows starting from column[2] to [last column]-1 with the value "qq" in tbl1(in sql server database) you can modify it according to your code.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl1 ", con);
   con.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            
    da.Fill(DS,"stud");

    for (int i = 0; i < DS.Tables["stud"].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int c= 2; c < DS.Tables["stud"].Columns.Count-1; c++)
        {
          DS.Tables["stud"].Rows[i][c] = "qq";
        }
     }
  SqlCommandBuilder  sqlb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
  da.Update(DS, "stud");
  con.Close();
```