# DataSet is Not Updating

Tags: c#

A dataset Ds1 is created, with one table TblEg1
a datatable is created like this.

```
DataTable TblEg1 = Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"];
DataRow row;
row= TblEg1.NewRow();
row["EmployeeID"] = "Malavika";   
row["EmployeeCode"] = "100";
TblEg1.Rows.Add(row);
```

and data add like above
Now mt data set contain the correct value. Now i want to sort table using EmployeeCode

```
var varWps1 = TblEg1.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(i => i.Field<string>("EmployeeCode"));
if (varWps1.Any())
   TblEg1 = varWps1.CopyToDataTable();
```

Now the table TblEg1 is updated Bt Dataset is not updating.
how can i made changes in data set too..

Comment: How you are getting data in `DataSet`?

Comment: Thank you for your response :)   DataTable TblEg1 = Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"]; using  this code, i got the exact copy of datatable created in dataset Ds1. and if i add rows to that Datatable TblEg1  dataset is also updated

Comment: Have a look at [How to update a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008748/how-to-update-a-dataset)

Comment: I tried it but it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"].DefaultView.Sort ="EmployeeCode";
```

By doing this you won't need to use LINQ and create another table. This should update the data set with the sorted table.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) . Again its not working.. the data table is modified with all changes .. But data set is  not updating.

Comment: What do you mean by "not updating"?

Comment: All the data of table has shown in datasetat first, then i have used ORDER BY to order the data in that table then the order datatable data  has been changed. But im not able to include this change in data set. Still the data's in dataset is in old order .

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code above, your data set should update correctly as you modify `TblEg1` table. Your code should add a new row and it should reflect to `Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"]`.

```
DataTable TblEg1 = Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"];
DataRow row;
row= TblEg1.NewRow();
row["EmployeeID"] = "Malavika";   
row["EmployeeCode"] = "100";
TblEg1.Rows.Add(row);
```

You can sort your data tables using

```
Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"].DefaultView.Sort = "EmployeeCode ASC"; // Set ASC or DESC
DataTable dvDT = Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"].DefaultView.ToTable(); // new table contains the sorted rows
```

At this point you should be getting `Malavika 100` when accessing `Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"].Rows`.
If you are still not getting the value using your data set, I see the possibility of you showing an incomplete code.

Here is a quick example:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new FooBar.FooDataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1["A"] = 3;
        dr1["B"] = 4;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

        DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
        dr2["A"] = 1;
        dr2["B"] = 2;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr["A"] + " " + dr["B"]);
        }

        ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "A";
        DataTable dvDT = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dvDT.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr["A"] + " " + dr["B"]);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT:

Here is a simple hack to copy ordered rows to your `Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"]`.

```
Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"].Clear(); // Clear table
Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"].Merge(dvDT); // Merge ordered table
```

Comment: Able to order the data in datatable, but i need to implement the same changes which i have made in datatable to be effected in dataset too

Comment: If the table you modified is the instance from the dataset then it should reflect automatically as you can see in my example. If not, then you can simply use `Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"] = dvDT;` after sorting.

Comment: data set is not modifying.. I cannot use this code  Ds1.Tables["TblEg1"] = dvDT; beacuse an error occured Property or indexer'System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[string] cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: @Malavika sorry for the late response. In case you still need it, I updated my answer.