# Dataset update via its datatables

Tags: c#

I want to Update a DataSet via a function

```
private void UpdateMydataset(ref  DataSet MyDataSet, int t)
{
    double W24= 0.0;
    MyDataSet.Tables[t].Rows[2][4+1]= W24.ToString();
    MyDataSet.Tables[t].AcceptChanges();        
}
```

before I call UpdateMydataset

```
Console.WriteLine(MyDataSet.Tables[t].Rows[2][4+1].ToString());
```

// output = 1

//After UpdateMydataset call

```
int t=2;
UpdateMydataset(ref  MyDataSet, t);

Console.WriteLine(MyDataSet.Tables[t].Rows[2][4+1].ToString());
```

// output still gives 1

Comment: You need to `AcceptChanges` on your dataset before breaking out of your `UpdateMydataset` method. How to update dataset? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008748/how-to-update-a-dataset

Comment: Can you post more details on how you are using your code?

Comment: I changed the function 
private void UpdateMydataset(ref  MyDataSet, int t)
{
    double W24= 0.0;
    MyDataSet.Tables[t].Rows[2][4+1]= W24.ToString();
    MyDataSet.Tables[t].AcceptChanges();
}
It still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.AcceptChanges();` after updating `MyDataSet.Tables` like below:

```
private void UpdateMydataset(ref  MyDataSet, int t)
{
    double W24= 0.0;
    MyDataSet.Tables[t].Rows[2][4+1]= W24.ToString();
    MyDataSet.Tables[t].AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: I use the same code                                                                                   It still doesn't work                          Console.WriteLine(MyDataSet.Tables[t].Rows[2][4+1].ToString());                                                                 Gives the same output=1;

Comment: @rachid can you update your question and share the code on how you are calling this method?

Comment: @rachid Don't edit comment. Edit your question and show how you are calling `UpdateMydataset`?

Comment: Think you very a lot.  I found the error cause of the problem.